# Rails STI Parent Model has_many expecting type on associated class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

Given a STI parent model

```
class CustomForm < ApplicationRecord
has_many :templates` 
end
```

with a couple of subclasses that should have many templates. Why would the template class below:

```
class FormTemplate < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :custom_form
```

Why would Rails expect the FormTemplate to have a custom_form_type column defined?

All you need is the custom_form_id.

this was working before and even passes my CI but I did some other work that seems to have broken it :disappointed:

Here is the error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column form_templates.custom_form_type does not exist
LINE 1: ...CT “form_templates”.* FROM “form_templates”
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you didnt post all your code and the line of code caused this error. I will make a guess based on what you posted.

I think you added   `has_many :templates, as: :custom_form` to one of the subclass of CustomForm. It defines [Polymorphic Associations]

In the CustomForm model `` has_many :templates` ``, it doesnt make sense to me, unless you have a templates model which is a subclass of FormTemplate